# Reg ex for matching and removing number from a String in java

Tags: java, regex

I am looking forward to remove any number(with decimal) contained within a string.
**For Ex:**
Input: "The game received average review scores of 96.92% and 98/100 for the Xbox 360 version."
Output:- "The game received average review scores of % and / for the Xbox version."

I implemented this on using regex. But, my syntax removes the period at the end of the string as well.

**Code:**

```
if(token.matches(".*\\d.*"))  {  
    String s7=token.replaceAll("[0-9,.]", "");  
    s7=s7.replaceAll("( )+", " ");  
    stream.set(s7);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the regular expression:

```
\b\d+([.,]\d+)*\b
```

For an explanation of this regex, see http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5Cb%5Cd%2B%28%5B.%2C%5D%5Cd%2B%29*%5Cb.

e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "The game received average review scores of 96.92% and 98/100 for the Xbox 360 version.";
    System.out.println(
        input.replaceAll("\\b\\d+([.,]\\d+)*\\b", "")
    );  // prints "The game received average review scores of % and / for the Xbox  version."
}
```

Comment: This works, but if there is a number like 123,456 in the text, i need to remove that comma as well.

Comment: Try this "\\b\\d+(\\.\\d+)?\\b(\\s*,)?". Also you can shorten your code to input.replaceAll("\\b\\d+(\\.\\d+)?\\b(\\s*,)?", "")

Comment: @Vin I added the `,` in regex.

Answer (score 0):

try this regex `(\d|\.)+` ,this will match numbers(including decimal points) then replace the matching group with ""

try this.

```
 String str="The game received average review scores of 96.92% and 98/100 for the Xbox 360 version";
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\d|\.|,)+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        str=str.replace(matcher.group(),"");
    }
```

Comment: I need to remove if there is any "," between the numbers as well. As in 123,456.00 -> 123456.00

Comment: is this a different case if yes then try this , change regex to `(\d|\.|,)+` then in the loop do this `str=str.replace(matcher.group(),matcher.group().replace(",",""));`

Comment: No, this is the same case as previous. need to add the comma to the previous syntax for my case.

Comment: u said u want to remove all digits right? then how come 123,456.00 -> 123456.00 ? if your string is  " abc 123,456.00 def" are u trying to get "abc def" if yes simple replace the regex to `(\d|\.|,)+` , dont change anything inside the loop